# ClassNotFoundException for main activity - Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Just updated to Android Studio 0.8.2 and I'm suddenly getting ClassNotFoundException on launch for the main activity when one of my apps is built with 0.8.2.

The app is in version control (Git) so I've checked out old builds and they are now exhibiting the same symptom upon execution and they were definitely working just fine when built with 0.8.1.

I've tried clean rebuilds, gradle syncing, manually deleting build/ and, .gradle/ dirs, closing & reopening Android Studio etc. - I've checked out various old builds of my project and tested the APK on several Android devices, the issue is 100% reproducible with both Debug and Release builds.

Strangely, although this is 100% reproducible for this particular project, I have another project which is building and executing just fine.

I've pulled apart the APK that is output from Android Studio 0.8.2 with apktool, and the class is definitely there.

```
$ pwd
/Users/ben/Development/go-android/Go/build/outputs/apk/Go-debug/smali/au/com/glassechidna/go/content
$ ls
AddTripFragment$1.smali             CreateTripFragment$OnQueryTextListener$1.smali  CreateTripFragment.smali            MainActivity.smali
AddTripFragment.smali               CreateTripFragment$OnQueryTextListener.smali    GoActivity.smali                TrainTimeFragment$1.smali
CreateTripActivity.smali            CreateTripFragment$OnSuggestionListener.smali   GoApplication.smali             TrainTimeFragment.smali
CreateTripFragment$1.smali          CreateTripFragment$StopCursor.smali     MainActivity$PagerAdapter.smali         TripFragment.smali
```

Stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/a77bd8fffb03ddb37ff1

Manifest: https://gist.github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/ca7ee54d7562a0feab0c

Go/build.gradle[1]: https://gist.github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/f9a3a39d6f141e412dac

build.gradle[1]: https://gist.github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/2db744dd89e487325b65

MainActivity.java[2]: https://gist.github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/11a6335f56b6ababeeb4

Any ideas?

[1] Taken from one of the oldest commits, as it has less dependencies etc. cluttering stuff up. However, the issue is still 100% reproducible for this commit.

[2] Just the declaration.

Comment: Is the package name for MainActivity indeed `au.com.glassechidna.go.content`?

Comment: @matiash It indeed is (https://gist.github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/11a6335f56b6ababeeb4).

As I mentioned, app built and ran fine immediately prior to updating to 0.8.2. I've got plenty of old commits that were all compiled and tested just fine with older versions of Android Studio, which are now also failing with the same runtime exception.

Comment: Does it work with from the command-line:  ./gradlew installApp  ?

Comment: @yogurtearl "installApp" isn't a gradle task, however you did point me in the right direction, thanks! Now, I just need to understand "why" the answer I posted worked.

Comment: Sorry, I think it is ./gradlew installDebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning from CLI seems to have resolved the issue.

*Props to @yogurtearl for pointing me in the right direction.*

```
$ ./gradlew clean
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:Go:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.906 secs
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:Go:preBuild
:Go:compileDebugNdk
:Go:preDebugBuild
:Go:checkDebugManifest
:Go:preReleaseBuild
:Go:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:Go:prepareDebugDependencies
:Go:compileDebugAidl
:Go:compileDebugRenderscript
:Go:generateDebugBuildConfig
:Go:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Go:mergeDebugAssets
:Go:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Go:generateDebugResources
:Go:mergeDebugResources
:Go:processDebugManifest
:Go:processDebugResources
:Go:generateDebugSources
:Go:compileDebugJava
:Go:preDexDebug
:Go:dexDebug
:Go:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Go:validateDebugSigning
:Go:packageDebug
:Go:zipalignDebug
:Go:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.64 secs
$ adb uninstall au.com.glassechidna.go.debug
Success
$ adb install Go/build/outputs/apk/Go-debug.apk 
8553 KB/s (323343 bytes in 0.036s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Go-debug.apk
Success
```

## Update

Since running the gradlew commands above I can now clean and build just fine in Android Studio. Consequently, it would seem that Android Studio wasn't cleaning properly and that manually deleting build/ and .gradle/ directories wasn't sufficient either.

Now, I just need to understand why this worked and why cleaning and building in Android Studio didn't...

If you know about any additional state gradle/gradlew stores elsewhere that could be the culprit, I'd love to hear about it via a comment.

## Update 2

This issue has kept occurring for me on my Mac. I've noticed that when I build in Android Studio the "preDexDebug" task generated several warnings as follows:

```
objc[49452]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comparing a good APK and a bad one I could see that some of the generated DEX'd classes vary quite significantly between the two APKs. Unfortunately I don't yet know a solution to the problem (I'm stuck building with the Gradle Wrapper from CLI).

Comment: Bug reported to Google - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=73726

Comment: I downgraded my jdk as mentioned to 7u25 (before the JavaLaunchHelper bug was introduced) and it's fixed the issue for now.